# What are the difference in usage between Either and Except in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, error-handling, exception, user-input

I have a class that can be created from several arguments in Haskell which requires some complex validation of those arguments. Currently I have something like

```
makeAThingExcept :: String -> String -> ... String -> Except ThingError AThing
makeAThingExcept s1 s2 ... = do
    unless (s1CheckPasses s1) (throwError (BadS1 s1))
    ...

data ThingError = BadS1 String ...

instance Show ThingError where
        show (BadS1 s) = "Bad S1: " ++ s

makeAThing :: String -> String -> ... String -> AThing
makeAThing s1 s2 ... = case runExcept (makeAThingExcept s1 s2 ...) of
        Right thing  -> thing
        Left err -> error (show err)
```

Setting aside whether there is a better way to do this by using more specific types than `String` as arguments to `makeAThingExcept`, is there a reason to prefer `Except` over `Either` in a case like this? What are the differences here between the capabilities and idiom of `Except` vs `Either`?

Comment: It probably comes down what type class instances are defined for `Except`; you can convert between `Except` and `Either` using `except` and `runExcept`.

Comment: @chepner Ah, so there's some fluidity there, wrt. tuning `Except` vs `Either` depending on context.

Comment: Here [in my package](https://github.com/orome/crypto-enigma-hs/blob/develop/Crypto/Enigma.hs#L319), FWIW, getting a valid `AThing` is really essential, and entering valid args can be a bit tricky. So failure from user input (e.g. from a typo) can be common; but in code, something would have had to go quite wrong with whatever was generating the arguments: code that supplied bad arguments would be doing a bad job of making `AThing`s.

Comment: So, naively, the former case is like an "either" or even a "maybe" (it could happen fix it and try again), while the latter is closer to an "exception" (your code isn't specifying `AThing`s correctly).

Comment: You'll have to wait for someone who actually knows to provide an answer :) I *think* the only real difference is that the name `ExceptT` was introduced to provide a type that was semantically devoted to error handling, as opposed to `Either` which is the generic way to define sum types, only one application of which is to provide error-handling semantics.

Comment: @chepner: How do I import `except` (or for that mater `ExceptT` as a constructor). I can't seem to make an `Except` from an `Either`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, it's easy to convert between `Except` & `Either`.  The runtime representation is the same, even.

I would always choose to use `Either`.  It's ubiquitous in libraries.  I very rarely see `Except`.

`Except` is a special case of [ExceptT](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html#t:ExceptT), which you *will* see in libraries.  If you find yourself writing a lot of functions with `Reader SomeType (Either e a)` or `IO (Either e a)` or `Monad m => m (Either e a)`, then you might want to consider `ExceptT`.  It's fine not to worry about it until then - `Either` is easier to use until it isn't.

Comment: I have a [follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53453944/656912).

Answer (score 6):

The difference is in the instance of `Alternative`. The "base" package does not export any for `Either`, as I understand because the authors didn't want to introduce a bias towards any of the values, which on itself is because `Either` is supposed to be a general sum-type, and representing the possibility of errors is only a special case. However [the "transformers" package does provide an orphan instance](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Error.html#v:-36-fAlternativeEither), which binds it to [the `Error` class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Error.html):

```
Error e => Alternative (Either e)
```

However the community has never accepted either the typeclass or the orphan instance, which is why it is now deprecated. IOW you can look at it as if `Either` still has no instance of `Alternative`.

The `Except` type does have a non-orphan instance, which doesn't even bind the user to any made-up classes, but `Monoid` instead:

```
(Monad m, Monoid e) => Alternative (ExceptT e m)
```

It is also worth noting, that for cases when dealing with validation and accumulating all errors, [the `Validation` abstraction](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/validation-selective-0.1.0.0/docs/Validation.html) is more appropriate. There is a tradeoff though: it cannot be a monad, but it is a selective (between applicative and monad) and an alternative.