# What purpose does the complexity of `Except` serve in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, error-handling, exception, monads, monad-transformers

I [understand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53192859/656912) (I think) that there is a close relationship between `Either` and `Except` in Haskell, and that it is easy to convert from one to the other. But I'm a bit confused about best practices for handling errors in Haskell and under what circumstances and scenarios I would choose one over the other. For example, in the [example](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-Except.html#g:3) provided in `Control.Monad.Except`, `Either` is used in the definition

```
type LengthMonad = Either LengthError
```

so that `calculateLength "abc"` is

```
Right 3
```

If instead one were to define

```
type LengthMonad = Except LengthError
```

then `calculateLength "abc"` would be

```
ExceptT (Identity (Right 3))
```

I'm confused about what purpose this would serve and when one one want it. Why does everything returned from `calculateLength` always have `Identity`; why not just `SomeExceptionType (Right 3)` or even `SomeSuccessType 3`?

I'm a Haskell beginner when it comes to concepts like this, so a concrete example of when I'd want the latter over the former would be much appreciated, especially why it's so (apparently to me) complex. For example, what can a caller of a function that uses the `Except` version of `calculateLength` do, that they can't (or at least can't as easily) do with the `Either` version?

Comment: `ExceptT` is a monad transformer. When explaining monad transformers like `ExceptT`, I often find it useful to think of it as a lightweight wrapper around `m (Either e a)`, where `m` is any monad. For instance, using `ExceptT e IO a` rather than `IO (Either e a)` allows you to use `IO`'s monad instance with `Either`'s monad instance without composing them yourself (by `fmap`ping twice for example). I can add more details if nobody replies first.

Comment: @JuanPabloSantos: One way of looking at this question is simply: which is better for potential consumers of my package and why? For my internal uses I don't really care much (I can easy convert) but what's the most flexible for potential users of my package's API: what, for example, can they do with the `Except` version that they can't do with the `Either` version?

Comment: For an example of the kind of problems addressed by `ExceptT` see e.g. this recent question and its answers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53426475/126014

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Abstract

Use `Either` for normal *success/error* APIs. It's defined in the *base* library, so it doesn't push other dependencies on a consumer. Also, this is one of the most basic Haskell types, so 'everyone' understands how it works.

Only use `ExceptT` if you specifically need to combine `Either` with another monad (such as, for example `IO`). This type is defined in the *transformers* library, so pushes an extra dependency on consumers. Additionally, monad transformers is a more advanced feature of Haskell, so you can't expect everyone to understand how to use it.

## Speculation on reasons

I wasn't around when those decisions were made, but [it seems that there are various historical reasons for the confusion](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/3ded39/why_cant_we_have_an_eithert_in_transformers/). Haskell is an *old* language (older than Java!), so even though efforts have been made to streamline it and rectify old mistakes, some still remain. As far as I can tell, the `Either`/`ExceptT` confusion is one of those situations.

I'm *speculating* that `Either` is older than the concept of monad transformers, so I imagine that the type `Either` was introduced to the *base* library early in the history of Haskell.

The same thing seems to be the case with `Maybe`.

Other monads, likes e.g. *Reader* and *State* seem to have been introduced (or at least 'retconned') together with their monad transformers. For example, `Reader` is just a *special case* of `ReaderT`, where the 'other' `Monad` is `Identity`:

```
type Reader r = ReaderT r Identity
```

The same goes for `StateT`:

```
type State s = StateT s Identity
```

That's the general pattern for many of the monads defined in the *transformers* library. `ExceptT` just follows the pattern by defining `Except` as the special case of `ExceptT`.

There are exceptions to that pattern. For example, `MaybeT` doesn't define `Maybe` as a special case. Again, I believe that this is for historical reasons; `Maybe` was probably around long before anyone started work on the *transformers* library.

The story about `Either` seems even more convoluted. As far as I can tell, there *was*, originally, an `EitherT` monad transformer, but apparently (I forget the details) there was something wrong with the way that it behaved (it probably broke some laws), so it was replaced with another transformer called `ErrorT`, which again turned out to be wrong. Third time's the charm, I suppose, so `ExceptT` was introduced.

The `Control.Monad.Trans.Except` module follows the pattern of most other monad transformers by defining the 'uneffectful' special case using a type alias:

```
type Except e = ExceptT e Identity
```

I suppose it does that because it can, but it may be unfortunate, because it's confusing. There's definitely prior art that suggests that a monad transformer doesn't have to follow that pattern (e.g. `MaybeT`), so I think it would have been better if the module hadn't done that, but it does, and that's where we are.

I would essentially ignore the `Except` type and use `Either` instead, but use `ExceptT` if a transformer is required.

Comment: [1/2] "Retconning" isn't a bad way to describe it. Originally there was `ErrorT`, but the  `Monad` instance for that transformer demanded a spurious `Error` constraint on the left type. `EitherT`, which is very much like the `MaybeT` you mention, was introduced, in a separate library, to avoid that. When *transformers* decided to correct the misstep, it was decided to not adopt `EitherT` wholesale, but rather rename it to `ExceptT` and introduce the `Except` synonym.

Comment: [2/2] Supporters of that choice argue that `Either` is supposed to be a neutral sum type that shouldn't be tied to exception semantics. It is a similar argument to that often made against instances of `Functor` and friends for tuples. For a closer look at the arguments, see [this thread in the libraries mailing list](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2013-August/020565.html). Personally, I think having `ExceptT` instead of `EitherT` just creates avoidable confusion, as seen in this very question.

Comment: This is very helpful. Online there's a lot of confusing and contradictory advice on how to approach errors in Haskell, some of it sounds out of date, and most of it veers towards dogma or at best deep theory. `Either` seems a pretty natural choice for most purposes. I expect that `ExceptT` is something that's useful when it's useful (and then the problem at hand makes it clear why it's useful).

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on "uneffectful"? That's a big part fo what was confusing me.

Comment: @orome The `Identity` monad is a no-op monad that adds no additional 'effects'. Haskell exists in relationship with mathematics (particularly category theory), so if a 'thing' exists in mathematics, you can frequently find it in Haskell as well, even if it's, at first glance, of limited value. `Identity` fits that category well. At first glance, it's not evident how it adds any value, but it can be used to turn a monadic API into an API without effects, in case you need that.

Comment: Yes, that's a good way to characterize it. One of the things that's unfortunate here is the nomenclature. `Except` is pretty misleading (as is `ExceptT`). If it had been `EitherT` I think I'd have seem the light sooner.