# What happened to Haskell's EitherT?

Tags: loops, haskell, monad-transformers, either

When reading an old (2012) blog post titled [Breaking from a Loop](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/07/breaking-from-loop.html) by Gabriel Gonzalez it became apparent that the spotlighted `EitherT` has somehow left the ecosystem. The [EitherT package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/EitherT) states that it is deprecated in favour of [either](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/either) - which actually doesn't concern itself with monad transformers at all.

I noticed that there was an attempt to clean up the error handling mess that seemed to have existed 10 years or so ago. My guess is that `EitherT` was not needed anymore.

I think the loop-breaking approach presented in the blog post is quite neat. So I'm wondering: What is today's replacement of `EitherT`. The critique of `ErrorT`, for this purpose, still stands, I think, and `ContT` is indeed rather heavy machinery for this little problem.

For reference, here's the idiom discussed in the blog post:

```
import Control.Monad.Transfomers.EitherT

exit = left 

main = runEitherT $ forever $ do
    str <- lift getLine
    when (str == "exit") $ exit ()
```

(By the way, there is [Control.Break](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/break-1.0.2/docs/Control-Break.html) by the same author that circumvents the whole `EitherT`, `ErrorT`, `ContT`, `ExceptT` mess.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53456278/126014

Comment: @MarkSeemann Something is wrong with `EitherT`, enter `ErrorT`, again not ok Either ;-), so now we have `ExceptT`? Yeah, that's what I was referring to with "attempt to clean up error handling". So `ExceptT` is just a rebranded `EitherT` with exception semantics?

Comment: `ExceptT` is exactly the same as your `EitherT`. The only difference is in the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Today's replacement for `EitherT` is `ExceptT`:

```
import Control.Monad.Except

-- use `throwError` in place of `left`
exit = throwError

-- use `runExceptT` in place of `runEitherT`
main = runExceptT $ forever $ do
    str <- lift getLine
    when (str == "exit") $ exit ()
```